# Fire JavaScript Event When a DIV is in View

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Is it possible to fire a specific JavaScript event when a certain DIV comes into view on the page?

Say, for example, I have a very large page, like 2500x2500 and I have a 40x40 div that sits at position 1980x1250.  The div is not necessarily manually positioned, it could be there due to the content pushing it there. Now, is it possible to run a function when the user scrolls to a point where the div becomes visible?

Comment: https://github.com/imakewebthings/waypoints or https://github.com/stutrek/scrollMonitor could help too

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not automatically. You would have to catch scroll events and check for it being in view each time by comparing the co-ordinates of the div rectangle with the visible page rectangle.

Here's a minimal example.

```
<div id="importantdiv">hello</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function VisibilityMonitor(element, showfn, hidefn) {
        var isshown= false;
        function check() {
            if (rectsIntersect(getPageRect(), getElementRect(element)) !== isshown) {
                isshown= !isshown;
                isshown? showfn() : hidefn();
            }
        };
        window.onscroll=window.onresize= check;
        check();
    }

    function getPageRect() {
        var isquirks= document.compatMode!=='BackCompat';
        var page= isquirks? document.documentElement : document.body;
        var x= page.scrollLeft;
        var y= page.scrollTop;
        var w= 'innerWidth' in window? window.innerWidth : page.clientWidth;
        var h= 'innerHeight' in window? window.innerHeight : page.clientHeight;
        return [x, y, x+w, y+h];
    }

    function getElementRect(element) {
        var x= 0, y= 0;
        var w= element.offsetWidth, h= element.offsetHeight;
        while (element.offsetParent!==null) {
            x+= element.offsetLeft;
            y+= element.offsetTop;
            element= element.offsetParent;
        }
        return [x, y, x+w, y+h];
    }

    function rectsIntersect(a, b) {
        return a[0]<b[2] && a[2]>b[0] && a[1]<b[3] && a[3]>b[1];
    }

    VisibilityMonitor(
        document.getElementById('importantdiv'),
        function() {
            alert('div in view!');
        },
        function() {
            alert('div gone away!');
        }
    );
</script>
```

You could improve this by:

- making it catch `onscroll` on all ancestors that have `overflow` `scroll` or `auto` and adjusting the top/left co-ords for their scroll positions
- detecting `overflow` `scroll`, `auto` and `hidden` cropping putting the div off-screen
- using `addEventListener`/`attachEvent` to allow multiple VisibilityMonitors and other things using the resize/scroll events
- some compatibility hacks to `getElementRect` to make the co-ords more accurate in some cases, and some event unbinding to avoid IE6-7 memory leaks, if you really need to.

Comment: You can replace all the code in getElementRect with the built in element.getBoundingClientRect().

Answer (score 6):

Here is a solution that is ideal in 2022. The current top answer only allows you to observe one item, and has performance issues because it fires many times every time the page scrolls.

```
var observer = new IntersectionObserver(function(entries) {
    if(entries[0].isIntersecting === true) {
        console.log('Item has just APPEARED!');
    } else {
        console.log('Item has just DISAPPEARED!');
    }
}, { threshold: [0] });

observer.observe(document.querySelector("#DIV-TO-OBSERVE"));
```

This fires as soon as the item is partially on screen. Changing threshold to 1 will require the item to be fully on screen (so it will never fire if the item is bigger than the viewport). You can do values in between for example 0.25 to fire when at least 1/4 of the item is in view.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an starter example using jQuery:

```
<html>
<head><title>In View</title></head>
<body>
    <div style="text-align:center; font-size:larger" id="top"></div>
    <fieldset style="text-align:center; font-size:larger" id="middle">
        <legend id="msg"></legend>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
        <div id="findme">Here I am!!!</div>
    </fieldset>
    <div style="text-align:center; font-size:larger" id="bottom"></div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var $findme = $('#findme'),
        $msg = $('#msg');

    function Scrolled() {
        var findmeOffset = $findme.offset(),
            findmeTop = findmeOffset.top,
            scrollTop = $(document).scrollTop(),
            visibleBottom = window.innerHeight;

        if (findmeTop < scrollTop + visibleBottom) {
            $msg.text('findme is visible');
        }
        else {
            $msg.text('findme is NOT visible');
        }
    }

    function Setup() {
        var $top = $('#top'),
            $bottom = $('#bottom');

        $top.height(500);
        $bottom.height(500);

        $(window).scroll(function() {
            Scrolled();
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        Setup();

    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

It only notifies once the div comes into view from the bottom.  This example does not notify when the div scrolls out of the top.

Comment: again this is for jQuery, and while I am all for jQuery, in my situation I will not be able to use it.

Comment: Then please note that in the question, so people posting will know your limitations. It also seems both people posted at almost exactly the same time, so they couldn't have known.

Comment: They asked for a javascript solution and never mentioned using jQuery. This is like if someone asks for a PHP solution and you give them something that only works in Laravel and then say "you should have listed everything you're not using".