# Activate JavaScript when a user "sees" an element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am interested in making a statital "rating bar" similar to the one(s) here: http://gdgt.com/improv-electronics/boogie-board/1st-gen/ but I am not sure how I would do it.

Basically on the load of the page, it doesn't activate the element, but when you scroll down to the bars, it loads them.

How would I go upon doing somthing along those lines?

Here is the HTML I have so far:

```
<ul class="product-criteria-bars">
      <li>
    <div class="product-criteria-label">
      Accuracy and sensitivity
    </div>

    <div class="product-criteria-bar">      
      <div class="fill light-green filled" data-width="240" style="width: 240px;"></div>
      <noscript>
        &lt;div class="fill light-green" style="width: 240px;"&gt;&lt;/div&gt;
      </noscript>
    </div>
    <div class="rating light-green">8.0</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </li>
      <li>
    <div class="product-criteria-label">
      Ergonomics / comfort
    </div>

    <div class="product-criteria-bar">      
      <div class="fill light-green filled" data-width="240" style="width: 240px;"></div>
      <noscript>
        &lt;div class="fill light-green" style="width: 240px;"&gt;&lt;/div&gt;
      </noscript>
    </div>
    <div class="rating light-green">8.0</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </li>
  </ul>
```

But what else do I need to do, JS wise?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158991/fire-javascript-event-when-a-div-is-in-view

Answer (score 1):

You can use this Jquery plugin and the below code to check

https://github.com/teamdf/jquery-visible/

```
$('#element').visible()
```

Refer http://www.teamdf.com/web/jquery-element-onscreen-visibility/194/

Comment: Okay, cool, but is there a way to delay this and add an animation?

Comment: Yes. After identifying the element is visible, you can delay execution of the code that is going to give the animation effect. Delaying the identification portion itself is of no significance

Answer (score 0):

Check out the function `isVisibleInViewport()` in http://media.gdgt.com/assets/js/provisionals/product/index-31733.js

Looks like the site is using a listener on scroll to check for visibility.

Comment: Is there anyway that you could get that to work in a jsFiddle for me?

Comment: No, but feel free to try it yourself!