# Scroll Website - I want my navigation div change color when scroll pass a section

Tags: javascript

I am not using any frameworks. How can I make my navigation div change color each time I scroll through a section on my page?

This is my web page: http://www.noteid.com/scl

As you can see there is a nav on the left and `position: fixed;`.
How can I do this in Javascript?

Comment: I would say that you could use CSS and `<a>` tags, but you want the functionality when scrolling, not when clicking a link.  Therefore, I'd suggest looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158991/fire-javascript-event-when-a-div-is-in-view and changing CSS classes when in view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It you need to use the scroll event.

```
window.onscroll = function() {
    var element = document.getElementById('testDiv');
    if (window.pageYOffset > 400 && window.pageYOffset < 800) 
        element.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
};
```

This uses the pageYOffset property to set the background property.

http://jsfiddle.net/N82fS/9/

Comment: So if i want to scroll pass an area, specific a section, and it keep the color till the top of the section till the end of it?

Comment: It's just a basic example illustrating the concept. Use the scroll event to know that the scroll has changed and pageYOffset variable to tell you where you are in the page and backgroundColor to change the color. You can use if clauses, switches whatever you like. Would suggest jQUery animations if you need animation effects.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Bootstrap's ScrollSpy to do things like this.

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy

Comment: I try it once but it seem im too slow to understand how it work. I add everything in but nothing happen. Can you give me an example?

Comment: There is a strange symbol showing up right before the !DOCTYPE tag on your website that needs to be removed because it is breaking your site. Getting the DOCTYPE correct is really important for using Bootstraps tools.

Comment: When you download Bootstrap, it has a lot a really useful examples. The site also has simple examples here: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#examples

Comment: Thank Steve. I also read it but it is not working for me. And i do not want the div id show up on my link when i click on the nav icon too :(